# Does the SMT-Lib standard support the combination of theories?

Tags: constraint-programming, smt, satisfiability

I know that several works are trying to deal with the combination of theories in SMT. However, the SMT-Lib 2.0 language (http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/docs.html) doesn't say anything regarding this point. 
My question is whether it supports that, and what Solvers offer the ability to work with several theories simultaneously?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_Modulo_Theories to see which (combination of) theories are supported by differents SMT solvers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, the link doesn't contain any information! There is the list of supported theories/logics but no information regarding their combination.

Answer (score 0):

The SMTLIB `set-logic` statement sets the logic for your SMT instance. Each logic supports a different set of theories. This page has a list of all currently supported logics in SMTLIB2:

- http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/logics.shtml

For example, with the `QF_AUFLIA` logic you can use the `Ints` and `ArraysEx` theories together in one SMT instance.